# How to get JSON array data using express node.js

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express

I'm learning node.js and server programming with developing a toy project. I have a problem to get JSON array data and save the data to DB.
My JSON array data is below.

```
[{
   firstName: 'hello'
   lastName: 'world'
   email: 'helloWorld@gmail.com'
},
{
   firstName: 'hello2'
   lastName: 'world2'
   email: 'helloWorld@gmail.com2'
}], ...
```

[image]

But, I see errors like below. (It said 'cannot read property')
[image]

To get this data, I write this.

```
/* model/subscriber.js */


var mongoose = require('mongoose');
var uniqueValidator = require('mongoose-unique-validator');

var subscriberSchema = mongoose.Schema({
     batch: [{
        firstName: { type: String },
        lastName: { type: String },
        email: { type: String }
     }]
});

subscriberSchema.plugin(uniqueValidator);

module.exports = mongoose.model('Subscriber', subscriberSchema);
```

And, I made router like this.

```
var express = require('express');
var router = express.Router();    
var {mongoose} = require('../db/mongoose');
var Subscriber = require('../models/subscriber');

router.post('/list', (req, res) => {    
     if (req.body.batch){
         Subscriber.create(req.body.batch, function(err){
             if(err)
                 res.send(err);

             else {
                 res.status(201).json({
                     message: 'User created',
                     obj: req.body.batch
                 });
             }
         });
     }
});

module.exports = router;
```

I searched how to solve this issue, but I couldn't find the solution.
If you let me know how to use this with detail, I would appreciate you.
Thank you!

Comment: Why does you schema consist of only one property that is an array of sub-documents? I think you misunderstood the whole concept, as the "array" would actually be represented by the documents in the collection itself.

Comment: @NeilLunn I agree with you. I think I misunderstand of this. Because I'm sending csv file which is converted with JSON. Hmm Can you give me some advice about this?

Comment: Sounds like a different question. Maybe you [should ask that one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask)

Comment: Hmm Is this because my schema consist of only one property?